# Why has Kotlins SortedMap no .forEachIndexed() function?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, sortedmap

Kotlins `SortedMap` is "a map that further provides a total ordering on its keys."

As a result, it should be indexable. However, this extension doesn't exist

```
`sortedMap.forEachIndexed()`
```

Why not? Am i overlooking something? Is it performance reasons? Didn't anyone bother?

(Yes, i know, i could use a List<Pair<Key, Value>>, but that's doesn't feel like the "intuitive" structure for my usecase, a map fits much better)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the things that have a `forEachIndexed` get it either from `Iterable` or have it as an extension function. `Map` does not, but one of its properties, the `entries` is actually a `Set`, which does have `forEachIndexed` because it inherits from `Collection` (which inherits from `Iterable`).

That means that you can do something like this:

```
map.entries.forEachIndexed { index, (key, value) ->
        //do stuff
}
```

The reason I've added this to the already existing `asIterable().forEachIndex` answer, is because `asIterable()` creates a new object.

Answer (score 2):

[`forEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html) is an extension function on all sorts of `Array`s and also `Iterable`. `SortedMap` is unrelated to those types, so you can't call `forEachIndexed` on it.

However, `SortedMap` does have [`asIterable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-iterable.html) (inherited from `Map`), which converts it to an `Iterable`. After that, you can access `forEachIndexed`:

```
someSortedMap.asIterable().forEachIndex { index, entry ->
    // ...
}
```

However, the newer extension function [`onEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/on-each-indexed.html) *are* declared on `Map`s. Unlike `forEachIndexed`, this also returns the map itself.